# Having trouble creating a view to get last photo BLOB column and keep a single unique row per person_ID

Tags: sql

We have two views and are having problems creating a new view that joins the two and filters out all but the last row of photo BLOB data per Person_ID.

View one has demographic data with the following columns with unique rows per person:
Person_ID, Title, Dept, Role, Photo_ID

The second view has Photo_ID, BLOB_pic_column with multiple photos rows per Person_ID.

We are trying to join the two views using Photo_ID and only have the highest photo ID'ed photo BLOB data for that person added to the new combined view.

Thank you

Comment: Can you explain your structure?  How is it possible to have one row per person in view1 but multiples in view2, and the join key is `Photo_ID` - are there multiple rows with the same `Photo_ID` in v2 and if so how do I know which one you want?

Answer (score 0):

The logic for the first view is simple:

USE ODS
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, TELEPHONE, IS_STAFF, IS_FACULTY, OFFICE, TITLE, EMAIL, MainPERSON_ID, DEPARTMENT
FROM         dbo.XM_MASTER_PERSON AS XM_MASTER_PERSON
WHERE     (TELEPHONE >= 1) AND (TELEPHONE <= 9999)
ORDER BY LAST_NAME

Where the ID in this case is our main person ODS key and we are able to get one row per person.

The second view we are trying to join comes from a ID system database.  Its logic is:

SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT AccessControl.dbo.EMP.SSNO AS MainPERSON_ID, AccessControl.dbo.MMOBJS.LNL_BLOB AS PIC_BINARY
FROM         AccessControl.dbo.EMP INNER JOIN
                      AccessControl.dbo.MMOBJS ON AccessControl.dbo.EMP.ID = AccessControl.dbo.MMOBJS.EMPID
WHERE     (AccessControl.dbo.EMP.SSNO <> '')
ORDER BY MainPERSON_ID

That view uses two tables one called EMP (It is the main demographic table for the pic ID  system) that has our MainPERSON_ID in its SSNO column. It is not the SSN but it was the only available column we could place our main database person ID number.

The ID system use an internal ID called EMP ID. The problem is that for each person in that system multiple badge rows are possible and with each badge a unique pic is possible. We are trying to link the photo table with the EMP table to get us a new view with just the MainPERSON_ID and the last photo on file. We are then trying to combine that unique last photo to our main ODS view listed above. The issue is that the EMP table has one row per person but the photo table has a non standard amount of rows per person depending on how many photos they have taken. This is causing multiple rows per person in the final view.

Thank you very much for your help